# ICU - How to specify custom formats inside pattern strings?

Tags: localization, globalization, icu

Does ICU or any of its implementations allow specifying custom formats inside pattern strings? Here is what I am looking to do:

English:

> "{0} likes {1}."

Polish:

> "{0} lubi {1, accusative}."

Russian:

> "{0, dative} нравится {1}."

Here `accusative` and `dative` are language-specific formatters that return the inflected value of their arguments.

I am aware of the existence of [setFormat()](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/MessageFormat.html#setFormat-int-java.text.Format-) but that doesn't work for me because grammatical cases are language-specific and need to be set by translators rather than programmers.

Do you know any other localization frameworks that do support this?